# Iframe Add Form duplicates enteries in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, formview

I'm using a javascript called fallr (jquery-fallr-2.0.1.js) that I downloaded from jqueryscript.net a while back.  It allows the embedding of an iframe within the script and when the script runs, it slides down from the top of the page as an over-lay on the page that called the script.  Within the iframe, I have an ASP.NET form for inserting data into an SQL database.

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="MyForm" DataKeyNames="MyID" DefaultMode="Insert" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="96%">
<InsertItemTemplate>Fields</InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

When the insert command executes, it creates duplicate entries in the database.  On my development machine, it did not do this.  When I moved the website out to the production machine, it started doing this everywhere this script is being used.  I'm in a pickle because this site is schedule to launch soon.  Besides postponing the launch and rewriting everything, is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with IFrames. If you want to prevent duplicates, you need to fix your code. Preventing duplicate insertions is an application specific task that depends on many factors including the semantics of your data.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code.  I was in a panic, tired and out of it when I posted.  It hit me when I woke this morning that this problem started when one of our sys admins added a second NIC to the virtual the site is on.  We have https bound to one IP and http bound to another.  The adding of the second NIC also broke SMTP on the site, so this clearly has something to do with our network setup internally.  Before the second NIC was added, everything was working great.  This site is scheduled to launch Monday which is why I'm in such a panic.